# Are there any Secp256k1 ECDSA test examples available?

Tags: elliptic-curves, test-vectors, dsa

Are there any available test cases for testing elliptic curves like secp256k1 (Korblitz curves from http://www.secg.org/collateral/sec2_final.pdf)? For curves like P192 there are for example those values: http://point-at-infinity.org/ecc/nisttv .

Moreover, what other ways one should test an implementation of an elliptic curve to make sure it is working correctly in all the scenarios used in encryption software?

Are there any easy to understand examples/tutorials of how to program and test elliptic curve algorithms that are available online?

Comment: Both answers don't include any ECDSA test vectors, only testvectors for scalar multiplication of the base point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some test vectors for secp256k1 in the spirit of the test vectors you referenced:

```
 Curve: secp256k1
-------------
k = 1
x = 79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798
y = 483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8

k = 2
x = C6047F9441ED7D6D3045406E95C07CD85C778E4B8CEF3CA7ABAC09B95C709EE5
y = 1AE168FEA63DC339A3C58419466CEAEEF7F632653266D0E1236431A950CFE52A

k = 3
x = F9308A019258C31049344F85F89D5229B531C845836F99B08601F113BCE036F9
y = 388F7B0F632DE8140FE337E62A37F3566500A99934C2231B6CB9FD7584B8E672

k = 4
x = E493DBF1C10D80F3581E4904930B1404CC6C13900EE0758474FA94ABE8C4CD13
y = 51ED993EA0D455B75642E2098EA51448D967AE33BFBDFE40CFE97BDC47739922

k = 5
x = 2F8BDE4D1A07209355B4A7250A5C5128E88B84BDDC619AB7CBA8D569B240EFE4
y = D8AC222636E5E3D6D4DBA9DDA6C9C426F788271BAB0D6840DCA87D3AA6AC62D6

k = 6
x = FFF97BD5755EEEA420453A14355235D382F6472F8568A18B2F057A1460297556
y = AE12777AACFBB620F3BE96017F45C560DE80F0F6518FE4A03C870C36B075F297

k = 7
x = 5CBDF0646E5DB4EAA398F365F2EA7A0E3D419B7E0330E39CE92BDDEDCAC4F9BC
y = 6AEBCA40BA255960A3178D6D861A54DBA813D0B813FDE7B5A5082628087264DA

k = 8
x = 2F01E5E15CCA351DAFF3843FB70F3C2F0A1BDD05E5AF888A67784EF3E10A2A01
y = 5C4DA8A741539949293D082A132D13B4C2E213D6BA5B7617B5DA2CB76CBDE904

k = 9
x = ACD484E2F0C7F65309AD178A9F559ABDE09796974C57E714C35F110DFC27CCBE
y = CC338921B0A7D9FD64380971763B61E9ADD888A4375F8E0F05CC262AC64F9C37

k = 10
x = A0434D9E47F3C86235477C7B1AE6AE5D3442D49B1943C2B752A68E2A47E247C7
y = 893ABA425419BC27A3B6C7E693A24C696F794C2ED877A1593CBEE53B037368D7

k = 11
x = 774AE7F858A9411E5EF4246B70C65AAC5649980BE5C17891BBEC17895DA008CB
y = D984A032EB6B5E190243DD56D7B7B365372DB1E2DFF9D6A8301D74C9C953C61B

k = 12
x = D01115D548E7561B15C38F004D734633687CF4419620095BC5B0F47070AFE85A
y = A9F34FFDC815E0D7A8B64537E17BD81579238C5DD9A86D526B051B13F4062327

k = 13
x = F28773C2D975288BC7D1D205C3748651B075FBC6610E58CDDEEDDF8F19405AA8
y = 0AB0902E8D880A89758212EB65CDAF473A1A06DA521FA91F29B5CB52DB03ED81

k = 14
x = 499FDF9E895E719CFD64E67F07D38E3226AA7B63678949E6E49B241A60E823E4
y = CAC2F6C4B54E855190F044E4A7B3D464464279C27A3F95BCC65F40D403A13F5B

k = 15
x = D7924D4F7D43EA965A465AE3095FF41131E5946F3C85F79E44ADBCF8E27E080E
y = 581E2872A86C72A683842EC228CC6DEFEA40AF2BD896D3A5C504DC9FF6A26B58

k = 16
x = E60FCE93B59E9EC53011AABC21C23E97B2A31369B87A5AE9C44EE89E2A6DEC0A
y = F7E3507399E595929DB99F34F57937101296891E44D23F0BE1F32CCE69616821

k = 17
x = DEFDEA4CDB677750A420FEE807EACF21EB9898AE79B9768766E4FAA04A2D4A34
y = 4211AB0694635168E997B0EAD2A93DAECED1F4A04A95C0F6CFB199F69E56EB77

k = 18
x = 5601570CB47F238D2B0286DB4A990FA0F3BA28D1A319F5E7CF55C2A2444DA7CC
y = C136C1DC0CBEB930E9E298043589351D81D8E0BC736AE2A1F5192E5E8B061D58

k = 19
x = 2B4EA0A797A443D293EF5CFF444F4979F06ACFEBD7E86D277475656138385B6C
y = 85E89BC037945D93B343083B5A1C86131A01F60C50269763B570C854E5C09B7A

k = 20
x = 4CE119C96E2FA357200B559B2F7DD5A5F02D5290AFF74B03F3E471B273211C97
y = 12BA26DCB10EC1625DA61FA10A844C676162948271D96967450288EE9233DC3A

k = 112233445566778899
x = A90CC3D3F3E146DAADFC74CA1372207CB4B725AE708CEF713A98EDD73D99EF29
y = 5A79D6B289610C68BC3B47F3D72F9788A26A06868B4D8E433E1E2AD76FB7DC76

k = 112233445566778899112233445566778899
x = E5A2636BCFD412EBF36EC45B19BFB68A1BC5F8632E678132B885F7DF99C5E9B3
y = 736C1CE161AE27B405CAFD2A7520370153C2C861AC51D6C1D5985D9606B45F39

k = 28948022309329048855892746252171976963209391069768726095651290785379540373584
x = A6B594B38FB3E77C6EDF78161FADE2041F4E09FD8497DB776E546C41567FEB3C
y = 71444009192228730CD8237A490FEBA2AFE3D27D7CC1136BC97E439D13330D55

k = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926418782139537452191302581570759080747168
x = 00000000000000000000003B78CE563F89A0ED9414F5AA28AD0D96D6795F9C63
y = 3F3979BF72AE8202983DC989AEC7F2FF2ED91BDD69CE02FC0700CA100E59DDF3

k = 86844066927987146567678238756515930889628173209306178286953872356138621120752
x = E24CE4BEEE294AA6350FAA67512B99D388693AE4E7F53D19882A6EA169FC1CE1
y = 8B71E83545FC2B5872589F99D948C03108D36797C4DE363EBD3FF6A9E1A95B10

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494317
x = 4CE119C96E2FA357200B559B2F7DD5A5F02D5290AFF74B03F3E471B273211C97
y = ED45D9234EF13E9DA259E05EF57BB3989E9D6B7D8E269698BAFD77106DCC1FF5

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494318
x = 2B4EA0A797A443D293EF5CFF444F4979F06ACFEBD7E86D277475656138385B6C
y = 7A17643FC86BA26C4CBCF7C4A5E379ECE5FE09F3AFD9689C4A8F37AA1A3F60B5

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494319
x = 5601570CB47F238D2B0286DB4A990FA0F3BA28D1A319F5E7CF55C2A2444DA7CC
y = 3EC93E23F34146CF161D67FBCA76CAE27E271F438C951D5E0AE6D1A074F9DED7

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494320
x = DEFDEA4CDB677750A420FEE807EACF21EB9898AE79B9768766E4FAA04A2D4A34
y = BDEE54F96B9CAE9716684F152D56C251312E0B5FB56A3F09304E660861A910B8

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494321
x = E60FCE93B59E9EC53011AABC21C23E97B2A31369B87A5AE9C44EE89E2A6DEC0A
y = 081CAF8C661A6A6D624660CB0A86C8EFED6976E1BB2DC0F41E0CD330969E940E

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494322
x = D7924D4F7D43EA965A465AE3095FF41131E5946F3C85F79E44ADBCF8E27E080E
y = A7E1D78D57938D597C7BD13DD733921015BF50D427692C5A3AFB235F095D90D7

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494323
x = 499FDF9E895E719CFD64E67F07D38E3226AA7B63678949E6E49B241A60E823E4
y = 353D093B4AB17AAE6F0FBB1B584C2B9BB9BD863D85C06A4339A0BF2AFC5EBCD4

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494324
x = F28773C2D975288BC7D1D205C3748651B075FBC6610E58CDDEEDDF8F19405AA8
y = F54F6FD17277F5768A7DED149A3250B8C5E5F925ADE056E0D64A34AC24FC0EAE

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494325
x = D01115D548E7561B15C38F004D734633687CF4419620095BC5B0F47070AFE85A
y = 560CB00237EA1F285749BAC81E8427EA86DC73A2265792AD94FAE4EB0BF9D908

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494326
x = 774AE7F858A9411E5EF4246B70C65AAC5649980BE5C17891BBEC17895DA008CB
y = 267B5FCD1494A1E6FDBC22A928484C9AC8D24E1D20062957CFE28B3536AC3614

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494327
x = A0434D9E47F3C86235477C7B1AE6AE5D3442D49B1943C2B752A68E2A47E247C7
y = 76C545BDABE643D85C4938196C5DB3969086B3D127885EA6C3411AC3FC8C9358

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494328
x = ACD484E2F0C7F65309AD178A9F559ABDE09796974C57E714C35F110DFC27CCBE
y = 33CC76DE4F5826029BC7F68E89C49E165227775BC8A071F0FA33D9D439B05FF8

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494329
x = 2F01E5E15CCA351DAFF3843FB70F3C2F0A1BDD05E5AF888A67784EF3E10A2A01
y = A3B25758BEAC66B6D6C2F7D5ECD2EC4B3D1DEC2945A489E84A25D3479342132B

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494330
x = 5CBDF0646E5DB4EAA398F365F2EA7A0E3D419B7E0330E39CE92BDDEDCAC4F9BC
y = 951435BF45DAA69F5CE8729279E5AB2457EC2F47EC02184A5AF7D9D6F78D9755

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494331
x = FFF97BD5755EEEA420453A14355235D382F6472F8568A18B2F057A1460297556
y = 51ED8885530449DF0C4169FE80BA3A9F217F0F09AE701B5FC378F3C84F8A0998

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494332
x = 2F8BDE4D1A07209355B4A7250A5C5128E88B84BDDC619AB7CBA8D569B240EFE4
y = 2753DDD9C91A1C292B24562259363BD90877D8E454F297BF235782C459539959

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494333
x = E493DBF1C10D80F3581E4904930B1404CC6C13900EE0758474FA94ABE8C4CD13
y = AE1266C15F2BAA48A9BD1DF6715AEBB7269851CC404201BF30168422B88C630D

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494334
x = F9308A019258C31049344F85F89D5229B531C845836F99B08601F113BCE036F9
y = C77084F09CD217EBF01CC819D5C80CA99AFF5666CB3DDCE4934602897B4715BD

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494335
x = C6047F9441ED7D6D3045406E95C07CD85C778E4B8CEF3CA7ABAC09B95C709EE5
y = E51E970159C23CC65C3A7BE6B99315110809CD9ACD992F1EDC9BCE55AF301705

k = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336
x = 79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798
y = B7C52588D95C3B9AA25B0403F1EEF75702E84BB7597AABE663B82F6F04EF2777
```

The vectors were generated using the open source library [hxBitcoin](http://hxbitcoin.com/).

Disclosure: I am the author of hxBitcoin.

Comment: The large (115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494317 and below them in your tests) numbers might not lie on the secp256k1 curve.

Comment: @Zenul_Abidin "Might"? Either they do or they don't. Please substantiate your statement with evidence. The order of secp256k1 is 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337 (https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-messages).

Comment: If anyone is still looking for the open source library hxBitcoin, you can find it here on @ChuckBatson's github https://github.com/cbatson/hxBitcoin

Answer (score 15):

Here are five test vectors for secp256k1, which I just generated with my own code. My code is a generic implementation of elliptic curves; it has been tested for many curves for which test vectors were available (in particular the NIST curves) so I tend to believe that it is correct. Each test vector is a value $m$ (chosen randomly modulo the curve order $n$) and the coordinates $(X, Y)$ of the point $mG$, where $G$ is the conventional generator defined in section 2.7.1 of SEC 2.

```
m = AA5E28D6A97A2479A65527F7290311A3624D4CC0FA1578598EE3C2613BF99522
X = 34F9460F0E4F08393D192B3C5133A6BA099AA0AD9FD54EBCCFACDFA239FF49C6
Y = 0B71EA9BD730FD8923F6D25A7A91E7DD7728A960686CB5A901BB419E0F2CA232

m = 7E2B897B8CEBC6361663AD410835639826D590F393D90A9538881735256DFAE3
X = D74BF844B0862475103D96A611CF2D898447E288D34B360BC885CB8CE7C00575
Y = 131C670D414C4546B88AC3FF664611B1C38CEB1C21D76369D7A7A0969D61D97D

m = 6461E6DF0FE7DFD05329F41BF771B86578143D4DD1F7866FB4CA7E97C5FA945D
X = E8AECC370AEDD953483719A116711963CE201AC3EB21D3F3257BB48668C6A72F
Y = C25CAF2F0EBA1DDB2F0F3F47866299EF907867B7D27E95B3873BF98397B24EE1

m = 376A3A2CDCD12581EFFF13EE4AD44C4044B8A0524C42422A7E1E181E4DEECCEC
X = 14890E61FCD4B0BD92E5B36C81372CA6FED471EF3AA60A3E415EE4FE987DABA1
Y = 297B858D9F752AB42D3BCA67EE0EB6DCD1C2B7B0DBE23397E66ADC272263F982

m = 1B22644A7BE026548810C378D0B2994EEFA6D2B9881803CB02CEFF865287D1B9
X = F73C65EAD01C5126F28F442D087689BFA08E12763E0CEC1D35B01751FD735ED3
Y = F449A8376906482A84ED01479BD18882B919C140D638307F0C0934BA12590BDE
```

For self-testing an elliptic curve implementation, I suggest first verifying that multiplying $G$ by $n$ (the expected curve order) indeed yields the point at infinity. Then, do the following many times:

- Choose two random integers modulo $n$; call them $a$ and $b$.
- Compute $c = a + b$.
- Compute points $P = aG$, $Q = bG$ and $R = cG$.
- Verify that $P + Q = Q + P = R$.

If you go through this a few dozen times with no errors then chances are that your implementation is at least mostly correct.

A must-have reference on elliptic curve implementation is the [Guide to Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/ecc/). It is not free, but worth its price. Good university libraries will let you read it without spending a dime on it.