# EC public key with leading zeros

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, elliptic-curve-generation, secp256k1

Let us take example of `secp256k1` curve. The current known public key with most leading zero (in x cordinate) is:

```
pubKey = (0x00000000000000000000003b78ce563f89a0ed9414f5aa28ad0d96d6795f9c63,
          0x3f3979bf72ae8202983dc989aec7f2ff2ed91bdd69ce02fc0700ca100e59ddf3)
private = 0x7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff5d576e7357a4501ddfe92f46681b20a1 (half of order)
```

My question is whether is it possible to have pubKeys with leading zeros? For example:

```
private = 0x7ADD48F07237A85230BE8FE44E1F7E36FEAF649672AEEFAA0F5ABBAD1721A994
pubKey = (0x00006fcf15e8d272d1a995af6fcc9d6c0c2f4c0b6b0525142e8af866dd8dad4b,
          0xe6aca70f61450bb377bf212b8863f5aa2ff50675d3c72c1d84519f2b5b19e7fc)
```

OR to further explain my question, I know that the following publicKey is a valid pubKey for secp256k1:

```
pubKey = (0x00000351c77ba68ec21856ff85284e7ddd5a1b83d41fc6a1278c67ad9f2f5e7f,
          0x09624c553c74b14cde21f80ab4a2cc4dc2cb314d40515b7445a9e1f31a873a7d)
```

Does there exist an efficient attack to calculate private key for given pubKey, by the fact, that pubKey has leading zeros?

Comment: Not all $x$ values constitute a point on the curve, however, this may not prohibit desired leading zeros. Being able to control the output leaks information about the key, right? If you can do it, I can do it, too, BOM!

Comment: The public key consists of the base point G multiplied with a random vector $s$ which represents the private key. As these are modulo operations the likelihood to have multiple zero byte values is about 1/255 for the first point, 1/65536 for the next one etc. The operation is not reversible so I *think* that brute force is the only way for you or an adversary to get the "desired" public points. However, I'm not answering as I'm 100% sure that there isn't a mathematical equation that can be used to select private keys if you can control all of them.

Comment: I'd be both pleased and surprised if the present question could be _conclusively_ answered either way! Independently: that "current known public key with most leading zero" is the result of a deliberate design choice of generator $G$ that was not documented when made AFAIK. Knowing this design choice, a (small) speedup is possible when computing $k\,G$ (because $k\,G=2k\,(\frac12\,G)$ and adding $\frac12\,G$ is made a tad faster by the form of it's $x$). See mildly [related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/60420/555).

Comment: @fgrieu I think the generator may allow special attack. If something makes calculation easy, it can also make reversing easy. It is only a matter of time that this attack might come into public

Comment: Given a private key and public key, a bit setting oracle on the public key, that also returns the corresponding private key is equal to discrete log oracle. on the other hand, I cannot talk about the equality to xLeading Oracle.

Comment: @madhurkant: the gain possible is small (<20% on adding $\frac12\,G$). Even if we knew the private key for a public key with much smaller $x$ (which seems unlikely, precisely because we don't know how that would be possible jointly with that special $\frac12\,G$), the speedup would remain <40%. And [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60421/555) is an argument that (beyond such speedups) the choice of generator can't degenerate into another speedup by more than about 50%. My theories for why $G$ is as it is, and why that was not documented, do not include planting a major weakness.